# Date from excel changes when uploaded into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to upload an excel spreadsheet with a column that contains dates and also other text.

the date is in the format 1/24/2012 but when i load it into mysql it changes it to some decimal format e.g. 40932 ????

how can i just upload it as is, without it changing? o
What can i do i'm really stuck on this one!!!!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your MySQL schema for the table you are loading it into?

Comment: mySQL expects dates in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. That is likely your problem (along with the column probably not having the right type)

Comment: How are you importing from Excel to MySQL? What you're seeing is Excel's timestamp format.

Comment: @cillosi My Mysql colum data type is varchar

Comment: You would see the same value (40932) in excel, if you change the cell number formatting to "General".

Comment: @Pekka I changed the format to YYYY-MM-DD.. But still same issue.. I changed in format cells and then selected custom one YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @Jayanta Dey  Yeah i saw like that when i changes to General.. Any option on how can i load my dates to mysql

Comment: What value is now contained in the CSV file exactly?

Comment: @ Pekka it is showing as 1/24/2012. I changed to YYYY-MM-DD format but still when i click on edit. it gives back 1/24/2012

Comment: Are you using any library to load the data from Excel, or is this a csv or other file generated from Excel data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel holds date values as the "real" number of days since a base date, which can be either 1st January 1900 (the default for Windows versions of Excel) or 1st January 1904 (the default for Mac versions of Excel): the time is the fractional part, so midday on any given date is 0.5 greater than midnight. To add to the misery, Feb29th 1900 is a valid date for the Windows 1900 calendar.

Assuming the Windows 1900 calendar:

```
function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0) {
    $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
    //  Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
    if ($dateValue < 60) {
        --$myExcelBaseDate;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}   //  function ExcelToPHP()
```

if Mac 1904 base, replace

```
$myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
    //  Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
    if ($dateValue < 60) {
        --$myExcelBaseDate;
}
```

with

```
$myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
```

This will return a PHP date/time value (standard 1970 base date), that you can then format as you wish using date();