# Date stored in excel becomes a number while reading and storing in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, date, format

I'm using a script to read data from excel file and store it in a mysql database table.
It's working fine except for the field 'date' which is store in excel in "mm-dd-YY" format. 
The problem is "02/26/2014" becomes "41696" when it comes to php..

I want to store this field in "mm-dd-YY" format in mysql database table..

How can I fix this? 
Any help is highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298429/date-from-excel-changes-when-uploaded-into-mysql
Good Luck.

Comment: I was having the same issue when uploading the excel to mysql and converting the date. You can check with my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298429/date-from-excel-changes-when-uploaded-into-mysql Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: How exactly are you reading the Excel data? At which point and how does a string convert to a number?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I'm using a php script which reads each rows and columns in excel file. The date in excel file is formatted as 'date'. But while reading it I'm getting the value of this field in 'general' format.. 02/26/2014 in excel date format becomes 41696 in general format. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to use both `date` and `strtotime` as i explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about formatting date with `date` function and convert to a string with `strtotime`?

Something like:

```
$str = '02/26/2014';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($str));

echo $date;
```

this will output:

`2014-02-26 00:00:00`

in your case you just need to use function in different way:

```
$str = '02/26/2014';
$date = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($str));

echo $date;
```

this will output instead:

`02-26-2014`

This way dates are ready to be stored in db.

Anyway by seeing how you import excel data would help out.

Comment: Hi Fabio, Thanks a lot for the answer.. I have tried your suggestion but still having the problem.. The data I have is :- $str = '41696';  not $str = '02/26/2014';

Comment: can you please add part of code to show how you import excel data? This might help

Comment: Hi, below answer fixed the issue.. Excel holds date values as the "real" number of days since a base date, which can be either 1st January 1900 (the default for Windows versions of Excel). ExcelToPHP function converts 41696 to 1393372800. Then I have used $formattedDate = date("m/d/Y",1393372800); Final result is 02/26/2014.  Thank you :-)

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.